# Block systems in permutation group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I need to describe all possible block systems in cyclic group $G=\langle(1,2,...,n)\rangle$. I think, they look like $\{1 , d+1 ,\dots\}$, $\{2 , d+2 ,\dots\}$, $\dots$, $\{d , 2d ,\dots\}$, where d is divisor of $n$, but I don't know how to prove if there are some other blocks.

Comment: What is a block system?

Comment: If B is some block, then {$g(B)$ | $g \in G$} is called block system

Comment: And what is a block?

Comment: @DavidSheard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(permutation_group_theory)

Answer (score 2):

For each block system, the stabilizer of the block containing $1$ is a subgroup of $G$, and different block systems give rise to different subgroups.

The stabilizer of the block $\{1,d+1,\ldots\}$ in the system you mentioned is the subgroup of $G$ of order $n/d$. Since these are the only subgroups of $G$, these are the only block systems.